# Data class public properties to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I use following code to convert public properties of my class to a Dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ClassPropsToDictionary<T>(T classProps)
{
     return classProps.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(classProps, null));            
}
```

This works fine but I don't want reference members of the class:

```
public class Unit
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; } // OK
    public virtual Employee EmployeeRef { get; set; } // DONT WANT THIS
}
```

Which binding flag I need to avoid the EmployeeRef member?

Thanks

Comment: String is also a reference type, you need it or not? You mean properties ends with `Ref` shouldn't be included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Where` with `IsClass` property:

```
classProps
.GetType()
.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
.Where(x => !x.PropertyType.IsClass)
.ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(classProps, null));
```

There is no `BindingFlag` for that.Most of the  `BindingFlags` are relevant with access modifiers and inheritance hierarchy etc. They can't be specified to eliminate value types or reference types. If you don't want to eliminate built-in types like `string` then declare an array, put all the types in it then use `Contains` :

```
var allowedTypes = new [] { typeof(string), ... };

.Where(x => !x.PropertyType.IsClass || allowedTypes.Contains(x.PropertyType))
```

Since most of the built-in types lives in `System` namespace you can also simplify this:

```
.Where(x => !x.PropertyType.IsClass || 
             x.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName.StartsWith("System"))
```

Comment: Thx. Some tiny correction: x.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName.StartsWith("System") instead of x.AssemblyQualifiedName.StartsWith("System")

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ClassPropsToDictionary<T>(T classProps)
{
    return classProps.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(pi => !pi.PropertyType.IsClass || pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
               .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(classProps, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to include structs? you can also look at the IsPrimitive flag, even though String is also an object so you would have to include that seperately

```
classProps.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || x.PropertyType == typeof(string));
```